# Retrieve text from a textbox with multiple line in a single line windows phone / c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, multiline

I have a text box which accepts multiple lines. I have to read the text from this and send it to a server.

The challenge is when I send the the string it should have '\n' instead of a actual new line feed. i.e. If the input is as follows.

```
First Line
Second Line
```

I should send it to the server as

> "First Line\nSecond Line"

I think that i should send something like

> "First Line\\nSecond Line"

But I am not able to find the '\n' character to replace it.

```
    private string addReturns(string content)
    {
        char[] modified = new char[content.Length * 2 + 2];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < content.Length; i++)
        {
            if (content[i] == '\n')
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Found return");
                modified[j++] = '\\';
                modified[j++] = 'n';
            }
            else
            {
                modified[j++] = content[i];
            }
        }
        modified[j] = '\0';
        content = new string(modified);
        MessageBox.Show(content);
        return content;
    }
```

The MessageBox displaying "Found return" is not at all reached.

Please help how I can achieve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to replace new line characters with `\\n`. If so, you can just:

```
private string addReturns(string content)
{
    return content.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\\n");
}
```

Be aware that the technique you are using can cause issues. What if the user wants to add the text `I like having double slash and n like \\n this` ? How are you going to interpret this in the server side?

Comment: First of all. This is not working. I am getting the same result. It is not being replaced.

Comment: If I am right.. If the code which you have put should work mine also should work. So I guess the problem is the textbox is not at all returning '\n' when read as a string. Neither Environment.NewLine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set these properties in TextBox,

**AcceptsReturn='True' 
TextWrapping="Wrap"**

This will work,

```
    string a = textBox1.Text;
    string[] delimiter = { Environment.NewLine };
    string[] b = a.Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string s = string.Join(",", b);
    string r = s.Replace("\r", "\n");
```

Comment: It still is not working. Again the same thing. The string have neither Environment.NewLine or '\n'.

Comment: ok have you set these properties in your text box? AcceptsReturn = true;  and TextWrapping = Wrap;

Comment: actually when you debug and check you wont be able to see the \n .

Comment: Thats alright.. but i need to send it as JSON string. So if '\n' is included in the string the i would get the expected response. Yet i am not getting any response.